# Deploy asp.net application without compiling DLL

Tags: asp.net, deployment, code-behind, web-deployment-project

When I publish any type of asp.net application, my code is precompiled into various assemblies.  I would like to avoid this so that I can upload an aspx page and its corresponding codebehind file.  I understand the benefits of doing it either way, but what is desired here is the least risky way to publish changes.

How does one properly deploy an asp.net project without compiling assemblies?

Is the process different for each model (web app, MVC..)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sounds like you have a Web Application Project, and what you want is a Website Project.  With website projects, you can modify the aspx and codebehind files and not have to worry about recompliling them, asp.net will do that for you.  Web Application Projects need to be compiled for every code change.

Comment: If this functionality is desired, are we limited to only create website projects and forced to avoid MVC and Web Application?

Comment: I do believe that MVC is web application only.  Might be wrong, but I've only seen MVC done in a web app model.

Comment: On the difference between webiste and web app: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd547590.aspx

Comment: Related discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/590501/difference-between-web-site-and-project-in-visual-studio

Comment: I notice that everyone where I work picked New Web Applications without knowing the difference. Like trying to pick the highest fruit on a tree because it was highest. I love the web site idea of being able to make a fix from anywhere. I travel a lot and get minor requests for changes and it is easy to do with Web site format. These are my websites and I am the only developer. I guess I would rather pick the apples up off the ground and make cider out of them. The website users don't know the difference. I doubt ANY user says "Oh! This is an application!"