# How to create a solution file using vs 2008

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2008, solution

I have all the files for the deployment listed below :

-BIN
-CSS
-IMAGES 
default.aspx
PrecompiledApp.xml
Web.xml

The above files can be copy pasted in the webapps folder and default.aspx could be run from the browser.

i want to create a solution sln file from this. How to create a solution file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks as though you are creating a web site.  I've never been able to create a solution with just a website in it ([a web application is a different beast however](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590501/difference-between-web-site-and-project-in-visual-studio)).  However, I have found a workaround, although it's a little cludgy.  Create a new class library project (any project type will do really).  This will create the project file.  Then File -> Add -> Exisiting Web Site.  Point to your existing web site and add it.  This will create the solution file as you now have two items.  You can now delete the first project that you created.  This will leave you with a solution file with one web site in it.

Answer (score 3):

A solution is merely a container of projects. If you create a project containing these files, the solution file will be created automatically in the same directory (unless you specify otherwise).

Comment: Yes, create a blank project and just add the files to it.

Answer (score 2):

1. File -> New Project
2. Expand Other Project Types, Select
   Visual Studio Solutions
3. Under Templates, ensure you have
   selected Blank Solution
4. Enter a name and a location for the
   solution and click OK
5. File -> Add -> Existing Web Site
6. Select the folder that contains your
   website and click Open

Comment: but there is no solution file created

Comment: Yes there is.  Are you looking in the directory you selected in point #4?  Or are you looking for the solution to appear in the solution explorer?  If the latter, that is a configurable option in Visual Studio - Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions and then check "Always show solution"