# Unable to cast page as page class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm attempting to access data on a parent page from a user control. I understand this is not the best way to go about it and I do not want to get into that debate. This is HOW I have to go about it due to constraints beyond my control and pay grade.

I should be able to do this:

```
myWebBase myPage = (myWebBase) Parent.Page;
int x = myPage.getX();
```

But the class name myWebBase is not recognized. Anyone have any ideas why?

Comment: how is myWebBase declared, which compiler error do you get... your error-message is not very clear, the compiler does a much better job i would say.

Answer (score 1):

Is the content page in a namespace that hasn't been imported?

Comment: Actually, I continued Google searching on this and I believe the problem lies in how I created my site - I am not using a Web Application, I'm using a web site. based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251542/asp-net-namespace , I believe I might be unable to accomplish what I need to accomplish.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if its related to this kind of issue:

[Any reference to profilecommon causes error Value cannot be null. Parameter name: type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3454788/any-reference-to-profilecommon-causes-error-value-cannot-be-null-parameter-name/3457792#3457792)  ?