# which are the differences between open project/solution and open website in Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

Eg. opening a website as a project or open a project as a website.
Are there any differences between this two options?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open project / solution will open a .csproj file which contains a list of the files included in your projects, among other settings.
Website is just a folder with files / subfolders in it. You can't control which files are included , it just take the whole base directory content.

Answer (score 1):

They are different project types and are treated differently by visual studio.
You can see the differences [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590501/difference-between-web-site-and-project-in-visual-studio)

Answer (score 0):

It's the difference between a web project (aka web application) and a website.

A website in visual studio doesn't have an associated project file - it is just a collection of directories and files. Everything in it is part of the site.

See on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730880.aspx#wapp_topic5).

Comment: no - both have a project file, just if you open it as website and not save it in a know path, is going to be saved on default project path. But both have project file to remeber many thinks...

Answer (score 0):

**Open Website**: Here you do not need to create a associated solution file.

**Open Project** Here you can create a solution and in one solution can add many projects or websites. when you open solution then it will load all projects and websites that are included in solution.