# Must I upload compiled .dll files to get a asp.net site to work?

Tags: asp.net, iis

Sorry if this sounds like a noob question.

I downloaded this asp.net project from the live server - the client said it has everything needed to run. I don't know what version it is, but it doesn't have .designer.cs files, only .cs files, so I guess it's pretty old.

When I open the project in vs2008, it gives a lot of errors, so I can't compile it locally.

The questions is:

As I need to make changes in .cs files, do I only need to upload the .cs files to get it to work? Don't I need to compile the project and upload the .dll files??

Thank you!!

Comment: It sounds like the project needs to be compiled. You would need to post some errors to give us an idea as to what is going wrong with the project when opened in Visual Studio.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like you may have a "web site" type project:

[Difference between 'Web Site' and 'Project' in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590501/difference-between-web-site-and-project-in-visual-studio)

Is there a csproj file? If not, then you can be pretty sure that it is. This project type compiles dynamically, so the cs file is present on the server. I don't care for this type personally, and would convert it to a web application, but that's just me.

Comment: thanks, you're right, as soon as I open the project using "open web site", all errors are gone.

Comment: Cool deal. If you do decide to convert it (and I think you'll save yourself headaches in the long run if you do), you might check this article out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa983476(v=vs.80).aspx