# ASP.NET Web Site vs ASP.NET Web Application

Tags: asp.net

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [What is the difference between web application and website in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475938/what-is-the-difference-between-web-application-and-website-in-asp-net)
>   [ASP.NET: Web Site or Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-web-application)

To start a new ASP.NET project in Visual Studio 2008 we are presented with two options to go about creating a website,you can either create it as a new ASP.NET Web Site(File  > New Website > ASP.Net website) or an ASP.NET Web Application(File > New Project > ASP.net Web Application).

What's the difference between these two project types? Has got to do anything with the security or performance?

Im using Visual Web Developer 2008 Express edition.Does the Visual Studio Professional Edition have additional options to create ASP.Net Project?

Thank You

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-web-application

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-web-application or http://stackoverflow.com/questions/475938/what-is-the-difference-between-web-application-and-website-in-asp-net