# What does the WSP stand for in the WSP model of development? (DotNetNuke Module Development)

Tags: dotnetnuke, dotnetnuke-5, dotnetnuke-module

I'm reading this tutorial on DotNetNuke Module Development, and I'd like to know what the acronym WSP stands for in phrase "the WSP model of development".

I know what they are referring to when they say the WSP model of Development, it's the model of development where you hookup the entire directory structure of DNN to Visual Studio and develop the module from there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

WSP stands for **Web Site Project** in Visual Studio (File - New Web Site).
The other project model is **Web Application Project** or WAP (File - New Project - Web).

See also:

- [Comparing Web Site Projects and Web Application Projects](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa730880%28VS.80%29.aspx#wapp_topic5)
- [ASP.NET: Web Site or Web Application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/398037/asp-net-web-site-or-web-application)
- [Difference between 'Web Site' and 'Project' in Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/590501/difference-between-web-site-and-project-in-visual-studio)
- [What is the difference between web application and website in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/475938/what-is-the-difference-between-web-application-and-website-in-asp-net)